# Appending a function to an existing onclick event at page load

Tags: jquery

I have the following html code that is pre written by the app I am using, which I do not have access to, i.e.

```
<td align="center" class="shuttleControl"> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_reload.png" onclick="g_Shuttlep_v61.reset();" alt="Reset"  title="Reset"/> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_last.png" onclick="g_Shuttlep_v61.move_all();" alt="Move All" title="Move All"/> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_right.png" onclick="g_Shuttlep_v61.move();" alt="Move" title="Move" /> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_left.png" onclick="g_Shuttlep_v61.remove();" alt="Remove" title="Remove" /> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_first.png" onclick="g_Shuttlep_v61.remove_all();" alt="Remove All" title="Remove All" /> 
</td>
```

Based on the above code, using jQuery, would it be possible that when the page finishes loading, search for the img src "shuttle_last.png" and append to it's onclick call, my own function get_Count(); ?

That is, I would then see the following code when I do a view page source for this particular line, i.e.:

```
<img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_last.png" onclick="g_Shuttlep_v61.move_all();get_Count();" alt="Move All" title="Move All"/>
```

Is this possible - if so, would really appreciate a code sample?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will not this work:

```
$('img[src$="shuttle_last.png"]').click(function() {
    get_Count();
});
```

?

Comment: hi zerkms, how would I apply this to my same code above as I only want to add my own function to the shuttle_last.png onclick event?

Comment: @tonsils: that is how you can add your own function.

Comment: You shouldn't call `$(this).attr('onclick')();`

Comment: @SLaks: this will not work? Or you meant that it will be triggered automatically?

Comment: @zerkims: I don't think so.  Yes, it will.

Comment: @SLaks: hehe, it works http://jsfiddle.net/bZ2LZ/ But it is triggered automatically, so my advice is just wrong.

Comment: Hi zerkms - just wanted to let you know that I didn't need the $(this).attr('onclick')(); call. It worked perfectly without it. Thanks.

Comment: @tonsils but don't the click handlers fire in the reverse order from the way you specified in your question?

Comment: @Emmett: according to the http://jsfiddle.net/bZ2LZ/1/ - no. But I'm not sure this behaviour will be the same in all browsers

Comment: @zerkms True, it seems to work. Can you please remove the incorrect line from your answer, so as not to confuse people who arrive here from g00gle in the future? Thx